# Host Nuxt.js and Express.js On Ubuntu server via putty and run it all the time

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu, server, nuxt.js, putty

I have done a project for BE and FE (Express.js and Nuxt.js), but when it build and run it via putty on ubuntu server, this is what I get

[image]

Is that a way to make it live using Putty?
And what happens if I close Putty, will Express and Nuxt still be running on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a conventional way of exposing something to the Internet since it's not publicly facing the Internet (the only way right now to have access to your apps is to know the IP of the server, username + password of the SSH account).

Also, you're running the server in dev mode here, not something optimized in terms of speed.

You will need to use `yarn generate` (or `yarn build`) then `yarn start` on Netlify, Vercel or any platform like that for your Frontend (free service usually if using SSG).

Here is a whole list of places and how to host there for the frontend: https://nuxtjs.org/deployments

---

As for your backend, you may host it on Heroku, Render.com, Railway or any place of your choice (with a Node.js available).
Even a bare metal SSD can be good for such but it will require more setup overall.

Comment: Uhmm so its not possible to deploy it on ubuntu server?...

Comment: Its for internal use of company..

Comment: @JansenStanlie you totally can do that there too. Will just need to setup an NGINX/Apache server to serve the various web apps. Being used for internal use doesn't discard the fact that it could be properly accessible without a running SSH connection.